# Getting values separated by commas from a text box and storing as an array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, input

I'm not really sure how to word this, but basically I want to read in an rgb color in `xxx, xxx, xxx` format and store each `xxx` in an array.  I am making a program to convert rgb into hexadecimal.  Until I get my gui created (which may take me some time) I am executing and inputting in the terminal.

Currently this is what I am doing:

```
System.out.println("Enter the first set:");
rgb[0] = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();`
System.out.println("Enter the second set:");
rgb[1] = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the third set:");
rgb[2] = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

- I have seen people use `.split(",")`, is this the best way to do what I want?
- Would a regular expression work better?
- Anyone know any tutorials that I could use?  Most of the ones I have found have just left me more confused than I already was.

Just so you know I am not doing this for a project (before anyone accuses me).  I already have the algorithm and everything else works except for this.

Comment: Also, if you think this is a duplicate please post the one you saw as I did not see any in the search.  It was probably due to the way I worded it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

- Don't create a new `Scanner` instance each time you want to read input. Just create one at the beginning of the program and reuse it throughout.
- The `split` method takes a regular expression as its argument, and returns a `String[]` (splitting the string on each match of its argument). So if you're planning on parsing a string of the form `"xxx, xxx, xxx"` then `.split(",\\s*")` is probably your best bet. `\s` matches any whitespace character and `\s*` matches `\s` zero or more times.
- I'm assuming `rgb` is an `int[]`, so you could loop through your `String[]` that was obtained from `split` (as described above), call `Integer.parseInt` on each element, and add the parsed int to `rgb`.

---

**Relevant documentation**

- [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`Integer#parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: `split(",\\s*")` would seem more flexible to me.

Comment: I will definitely fix the Scanner.  The array rgb is an int[], forgot to post that in there.  Thanks for the parse info though, it may come in handy down the road.

Comment: Haha, silly me.  I will have to have the array as a `String[]`.  You won't be able to pass the `,` to an integer.  Thanks for catching that.  I didn't even notice it!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use split() method and it will return you an array.

Also your code looks redundant.
I would recommend using some sort of loop

Comment: I am hoping to replace all of this with one scanner / input and have it store the input into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, split is an option...

```
String[] strArray = inputString.split(",");
int[] rgb = new int[strArray.length]
for (int i=0; i<strArray.length; ++i) {
    rgb[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i].trim());
}
```

Scanner will work too...

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputString);
String match;
while ((match = sc.findInLine("(\\d+)"))!=null) {
    // here i print it, but you need to put it into an array (like above),
    // i'll leave it to you as an exercise
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(match));
}    
sc.close();
```